# Invoke popup as reminder in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a functionality where I need to remind the customers about their appointments before the time interval set while creating the appointment.

**Example**:
A customer is logged into the system today at **4:00PM**.
If a customer has an appointment set today at 5:00PM , and the reminder minutes as 10.
This invokes a popup with beepsound that has to appear today at 4:50PM(i.e 10 minutes before the actual appointment start time).
I have all appointments with start time, end time , (along with the dates) stored in backend table for number of customers.

Please guide me to achive the following in realtime :
(1) to invoke this popup at 4.50PM
(2) play the soundfile stored in the database

From my search,there is a way to do this using signalr concept in mvc. I went through the sample for chat application in this lnk. 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

This invokes the hub when a event occurs. but in my application it has to work as a reminder to show the popup if the start time matched the current time. how to get this in real time. Any idea can help me.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good situation to use WebSockets. (Take a look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), and it's .NET version [SocketIO4Net](http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/))

The idea would be to have a business logic server side to manage what customer has an appointment to be reminded. Then it uses the WebSocket to send the reminder signal. If the customer is logged in, the js client side would catch the signal and you decide how you want to show it.

To play the sound stored in the database, you could do an action server side that returns the sound file or something, and then use an HTML 5 tag to play the sound.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the approach, and use a `windows service`, **emailing/sms'ing** the user to remind them of the appointment, this means that the user doesn't need to be logged into the web application to receive a reminder.

If you wanted to use technology such as `SignalR`, you would need to keep a record of connected users (and their username) and then when an appointment is due, you would need to trigger an event to send to the user in question, based on the unique `connectionId`.

SignalR, out of the box, doesn't work like this - but, take a look at my question here for some help : [Update UI with SignalR and Knockout when manually updating DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459994/update-ui-with-signalr-and-knockout-when-manually-updating-db)

**Edit**: To add to this, if you're looking for a very nice notification plugin, then take a look at John Papa's [`ToastR`](http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr-1-3-0-now-available/), it's a small JS/Css plugin which notifies via a 'timed, outlook style notification'.

Answer (score 1):

Everything can be done but as ChristianDev says SignalR does not work like this out of the box... I think you can do this with SignalR anyway but you have a few challenges...

1. You have to maintain state on the server for the clients appointment
2. This state have to be persistent between connection, when a client navigates between pages
3. When an event fires you have to send the message to the correct client
4. If that client is between pages (offline) at the moment that message have to be stored until the client gets back online and then be sent to him/her.

EDIT: It seemed like a fun thing to write so a wrote a simple notification application. You can probably port it to SignalR pretty easy. [Realtime Notification Sample](https://gist.github.com/XSockets/6900894)