# SignalR - invoking a message from server code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Been researching heaps and making no progress :(
Trying to set up a small web app using VB in VS 2013.
I have added all the SignalR resources to my project.

Each logged in client has a UserID in my database.

I want to invoke a SignalR message to certain UserID's from server-side code, not client-side. Firstly, is this possible? (it was possible using ReverseAJAX, but I have chosen not to use that)

If it is possible, how do I go about setting up the SignalR Hub to allow me to send a message using a UserID? I don't need help with the SQL, I can do that my self.

Also, what javascript do I need to persist the request? I'm guessing I will need the UserID somewhere in this piece of code.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: see this sample. you can change it to use your userid instead http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: This might also help, it's a similar question to what I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459994/update-ui-with-signalr-and-knockout-when-manually-updating-db

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't see where i can use my UserID.
I dont need to trigger code when the database is updated. I just need to use the UserID database field to send a SR message to a client of that ID.

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible. If you look here

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

you will find a section on "**Single User Groups**". This is the mechanism available in version 2 to send a message to a single User Id. Essentially when a Connection is established you add the User Id to a "group" which can be accessed by Group Name (syn. User Id) without having to worry about persisting the relationship of a connection id to a user id yourself. The only limitation would be if more than 1 connection is established by the same user, all devices with that user would be in the same group and would therefore receive any messages sent to it...

There is also another section on how to retain the instance of your SignalR context on the web server to make calls out to clients (How to call client methods and manage groups from outside the Hub class)

I did read something about the SignalR team creating User Id methods but I have used the above approach with fair success and haven't looked much further into that.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this.

Comment: Also keep in mind you do not have to send anything special from script. You can digest the User within your .NET code if it is "authenticated" and pull the User Name directly from the ASP.NET Principal. Pretty easy to get rolling once you get started =D

Answer (score 1):

As @Pepto mentioned, [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) it is described how you can get a reference to your hub, and then use it in your server code.

An easy way to invoke a client-side function for a specific user, would be to use `Clients.User("Username")` in your hub.

Intellisense will tell you that `User()` wants an ID as a parameter, but you should pass the username of the user, whose function you want to invoke, not his ID.

Comment: Hey, I have not read the article yet, but in your post you say that the username should be used not the ID ? I am puzzled as to why you say this. UserID is always unique but username is not necessarily unique. Cheers.

Comment: This is simply the behaviour of the default UserID provider on the hub, as a user's username is readily available on the Request's  `IPrincipal.Identity.Name`. see http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider Since you can't have two users with the same username, this way of identifying users is more efficient than, say, querying the database for an ID.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for explaning. I had a skim through the big article and it's pretty overwhelming as I first have to figure out which bits of code I need, and then convert all the C# to VB.